# Is it possible to run a software from non-admin account giving it admin privilege?

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, administration

I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate 32 bit.

I know about the "Run as administrator". That will ask for admin password. My scenario is different.

A software came with my webcam (A4 tech) works fine in admin account. But doesn't start in non-admin account. I guess it uses some API that can only be executed from admin account and it doesn't check if it is executed successfully or not. In the absence of admins, non-admin users can't use it.

So, is it possible to setup an environment from admin account that when the software will be run from non-admin account it will get admin privilege?

Thanks.

Comment: What terribly written software! I would get my money back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try using compatibility mode on the program executable(s), you would do this for the program exe's, not the shortcuts.

You can also try uninstalling the software, then re-install it as an admin while in the user account.

Uninstall the software, right click on the installer and select run as administrator, install it and see if it works in the user account now.